# Removing nodes in LinkedList in Java

Tags: java, list

Okey, so I understand the basics of Linked Lists. I know how each node has a reference to the next node, and I get it how it's all tied up.

My code is working with no issues, but the issue is I just don't get how it's working (yeah...)

My question is about removing a node in the linked list. So let's say I'm removing a Person in my list, which is in the middle of the list. In my method, I'm just making a temp variable of nextPerson, and with the right logic, I'm deleting that node, BUT I'm NOT changing anything in the "global" nextPerson afterwards. The thing is.. It apperently affects firstPerson anyways and is actually removing that same node from firstPerson.

I know linked list are confusing, and so is my question. But if there's anything I'm not clear about, I can explain further..

```
  public class Store
{
    private Person firstPerson;

    void newPerson(Person person)
    {
    if (firstPerson == null)
    {
        firstPerson = person;
    }
    else
    {
        person.nextPerson = firstPerson;
        firstPerson = person;
    }
}

void checkout()
{
    Person temp = firstPerson;
    while (temp.nextPerson != null)
    {
        System.out.println(temp.getName() + " bought" + temp.getItem() + ".");
        System.out.println("- Hade bra!");
        temp = temp.nextPerson;
    }
}

//THIS METHOD:
boolean deletePerson(String name)
{


    Person temp = firstPerson;
    if (temp.getName().equals(name))
    {
        temp = temp.nextPerson;
    }
    else
    {
        while (temp.nextPerson != null)
        {
            if (temp.nextPerson.getName().equals(name))
            {
                //REMOVING THE NODE
                temp.nextPerson = temp.nextPerson.nextPerson;
                //NOT CHANGING ANYTHING IN "firstPerson", STILL CHANGES IT
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                temp  = temp.nextPerson;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;

    }
}



 public class Person
{
private String name, item;
Person nextPerson;

Person(String name, String item)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.item = item;
}

public String getItem()
{
    return item;
}

public String getName()
{
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of temp?

Comment: As I didn't understand why it's affecting nextPerson, If you look at the else-statement, temp is always changing.. I thought I needed to make a temp-variable so I don't mess up firstPerson..

Answer (score 1):

In java, variables containing objects really contain references to objects, so when you assign `temp` to `firstperson`, every time you use `temp` it is equivalent to using `firstperson` because they both reference the same object in memory.

Comment: Ah! That explains it. I feel like every tutorial fails to mention this important point.

But a follow-up question.. If you look at my code, I have an if else statement. Every time it reaches else, it changes temp so the next node is temp now. How come this don't affect firstPerson then?

Thanx for the feedback!

Comment: Can you clarify? As in give input and expected/actual output in your OP